# Find a variable in a value in a string Android Studio, Java

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner in java, i was wondering if i can find a value in a string.

Lets say that i have a `String` like this: "Number 5 hurray", and the number 5 could be any number, is there anyway that i can find what is in between the parts of the string '"Number ' and 'hurray"'?

Comment: The number 5 could be any number like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc... so something like "abc".contains("5") will not work, or can you use it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string by space char, and then you will have an array like this ["Number", "5", "hurray"]. So the number you are looking for is always on position 1.

```
String s = "Number 5 hurray";
String[] array = s.split(" ");
String number = array[1]; // here your number
```